# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() finds/returns object, but does not update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to find and update with this code:

```
exports.updatePlot = async (req, res) => {
    let modifications = {};
    modifications.name = req.body.name;
    modifications.grower = req.body.props.grower;
    modifications.variety = req.body.props.variety;
    modifications.planted = req.body.props.planted;

    const id = req.body.props.id;

    try {
        const updatedPlot = await Plot.findByIdAndUpdate(
            id,
            { $set: { modifications } },
            { new: true }
        );
        res.json({
            updatedPlot
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(422).send({
            error: { message: 'e', resend: true }
        });
    }
};
```

I can see that my request body contains data, I can also see that Mongoose is finding the object, but not updating it, because this is what it logs as the updated plot:

```
{"_id":"id string here","name":"old name",...all other properties...}
```

I guess my request is malformed? Anyone see my mistake?

The Schema looks like this:

```
const plotSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        ...other properties...
    },
    { bufferCommands: false }
);

const ModelClass = mongoose.model('plot', plotSchema);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting your `$set` object to this:

```
$set: {
    modifications: {
        name: 'xxx',
        grower: 'xxx',
        variety: 'xxx'
    }
}
```

However, what you want it to be is:

```
$set: {
    name: 'xxx',
    grower: 'xxx',
    variety: 'xxx'
}
```

Try removing the curly braces on `modifications` in the query, like this:

```
const updatedPlot = await Plot.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { $set: modifications },
    { new: true }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the request, try this one:

```
const updatedPlot = await Plot.findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: id},
            modifications },
            { new: true }
        );
```